# Java If Statement Trouble

Tags: java

I'm in college and am trying to learn Java but I'm having a bit of trouble with some code. The "if (totCreditsEarned >= 180)" is erroring in my Eclipse, specifically the part in parentheses, and it's unable to give any suggestions to fix it.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class CSC161lab6_1 {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Credits Earned: ");
    String totCreditsEarned = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Credits Earned is: " + totCreditsEarned);
    
    if (totCreditsEarned >= 180) {
    System.out.println("Wow!"); 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oof!");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you take a closer look at the error message Eclipse is giving you, rather than expecting an all-made fix ? It should point you in the right direction. What you are trying to do is use the operand `>=` on a String, which doesn't make sense. You'll have to *cast* your variable first.

Comment: @ArthurAttout *You'll have to cast your variable first.* - how would you do that?

Comment: Sorry, should have used the term *parse* instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`180` is an Integer.  `totCreditsEarned` is a String.

You will need to convert `totCreditsEarned` to an Integer

```
if (Integer.valueOf (totCreditsEarned)  >= 180) 
...
```

Of course if you enter a non-integer value it will fail

Comment: Oooh alright, I guess I was thinking of it more of C++ coding. So you can't just bring the data over from the scanner, it needs to be converted. Alright, got it, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The full compilation error is.

```
CSC161lab6_1.java:13: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>='
    if (totCreditsEarned >= 180) {
                         ^
  first type:  String
  second type: int
1 error
```

It's telling you that you can't compare an `int` and a `String` using `>=`. You need two ints, so `totCreditsEarned`  must be an int or converted to an int before you can compare them.

You can read it from the Scanner as an int. So no need to convert after.

```
int totCreditsEarned = scanner.nextInt();
```